# Serilog - ApplicationInsights sink - custom properties not logging

Tags: serilog

In my program.cs file I have added the serilog configuration

```
 loggerConfiguration                        
                    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                    .Enrich.WithExceptionDetails()
                    .Enrich.WithProperty("Application",builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Application"))
                    .Enrich.WithProperty("Environment",builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("Environment"))
     .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(services.GetRequiredService<TelemetryConfiguration>(), TelemetryConverter.Traces);
```

When I log error message with custom properties like this -

```
_logger.Error("user is not active {userObject}", userObject);
```

here userObject is a POCO class with few properties and  it get logged in the ApplicationInsights as a separate entry - `userObject` but the value is `"Testproject.Models.UserObject"` . It didnt flatten / seriliaze the object. Did I miss some settings?

Comment: that should simply work - try it standalone with the console sink to verify.
chances its something boring such as the properties on the object are private or something like that

Comment: in my console logging while debugging as well, I see the same output. :-(
All the properties are public.

Comment: I'd read the intro guide at serilog.net. My guess is that you want `{@userObject}` to trigger the destructure (there are other ways in which you can say that a given type must always be destructured too)